# Get just the doc with the maximal score. Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm new with Elasticsearch. Actually I began today.

I toke the "bank" example that they have and added the same account two times.

Then I wanted to see if I could get the account with that number, and it came three accounts with the same number. That's ok.

But then, I wrote my own "score interpretation" and saw that it works.

And now, I would like to get just the document (account) with the biggest score, but I don't know how to do it.

This is what I wrote as JSON:

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "account_number": "998"                                                 }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": { 
                            "lang": "groovy",
                            "file": "test-score",                           
                            "params": {
                                "boostBy": 2
                            }                       
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]           
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what comes:

```
{
    "took": 6,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3,
        "max_score": 33738,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "bank",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "998",
                "_score": 33738,
                "_source": {
                    "account_number": 998,
                    "balance": 16869,
                    "firstname": "Letha",
                    "lastname": "Baker",
                    "age": 40,
                    "gender": "F",
                    "address": "206 Llama Court",
                    "employer": "Dognosis",
                    "email": "lethabaker@dognosis.com",
                    "city": "Dunlo",
                    "state": "WV"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "bank",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "AVn6HUT-4vooOra1Vb9f",
                "_score": 33246,
                "_source": {
                    "account_number": 998,
                    "balance": 16623,
                    "firstname": "Bradshaw",
                    "lastname": "Mckenzie",
                    "age": 29,
                    "gender": "F",
                    "address": "244 Columbus Place",
                    "employer": "Euron",
                    "email": "bradshawmckenzie@euron.com",
                    "city": "Hobucken",
                    "state": "CO",
                    "aggregations": {
                        "testing_n_grams": {
                            "avg": {
                                "script": {
                                    "inline": "doc['grade'].value",
                                    "lang": "painless"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "bank",
                "_type": "account",
                "_id": "AVn6G6hA4vooOra1Vb9e",
                "_score": 33246,
                "_source": {
                    "account_number": 998,
                    "balance": 16623,
                    "firstname": "Bradshaw",
                    "lastname": "Mckenzie",
                    "age": 29,
                    "gender": "F",
                    "address": "244 Columbus Place",
                    "employer": "Euron",
                    "email": "bradshawmckenzie@euron.com",
                    "city": "Hobucken",
                    "state": "CO",
                    "aggregations": {
                        "testing_n_grams": {
                            "script": {
                                "inline": "doc['firstname'].value",
                                "lang": "painless"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to take just the account with the "max_score". Is it possible? Or I have to take everything and somewhere else decided what's the max score?

And I also want, that if there are more than one account with the max_score, it returns every account with the "max_score". That's why it doesn't work if I just write "size = 1".

Sorry if it's a stupid question, as I said, I began today with Elasticsearch and don't know how to do it.

Maybe someone there tried something like that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a good answer. So I use "size":1 as Shadocko suggested when I just need the first one. And when I need every data that match the max_score, then I just take the whole date and somewhere else I decided which data is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit how many documents ES will return using the `size` parameter.

```
{
    "query": {
        [...snip...]
    },
    "size": 1
}
```

[reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html)

Comment: thank for the answer! 
yes, but if there're more than just one doc with the max score?
is it possible to take every doc that matchs the max_score?